# React native: How to call REST api with upper case request header name

Tags: rest, react-native

In react-native, When I use fetch or axios to call RESTful API, those library lowercase all request header name (See [Github closed issue](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/610)). Is there anyway to workaround without changing the server (I call public API of the server that I can't change)?

Thanks,
Loc

Comment: I fear that may not be possible, as conveyed by the [standards](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2)

Comment: Ouch, this is frustrating. Servers and clients should treat headers as case-insensitive, but the reality is that some badly built servers don't support this.

Your best bet might be to alter your http client yourself to support this.